# Is it true that a multi-armed-bandit selects an action based on the future reward?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

During my machine learning lecture I saw the following statement on the slides: "Multi-armed-bandit selects an action based on the future reward"

Is that statement true?

In my opinion it is false because the selection of the action is not based on the reward directly as it is not known but on some strategy to maximize the reward in the long run.

Could maybe someone provide some references if it true or not, as I could not find any